# How can I add a WPF tabitem from Ironpython code and not XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, clone, ironpython

I have a tab control:

```
<TabControl
                x:Name="ContactTabs"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="1090"
                Margin="0,0,0,23.75">
                <TabControl.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush
                        Color="Green"
                        Opacity="0.30" />
                </TabControl.Background>
```

Currently I create a tabitem in XAML with the code, but I want to add the tabs dynamically instead from XAML, the Code I use is:

```xml
<TabItem
                Name="contactTemplate"
                Header="New Contact">
```

How can I create the tab using WPF and python code instead of XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I can do what I need by creating a new tabitem object like this.

```py
ContactTabClone = TabItem()
ContactTabClone.Name = "ContactClone"
ContactTabClone.Header = "ContactClone" 
window.ContactTabs.Items.Add(ContactTabClone)
```